# if f is a homomorphism from L to L', Should the image f(L) be a sublattice of L'?

Tags: lattice-orders, ordered-groups

I'm a beginner in the subject & my question can be meaningless, so I'm sorry from start if that's the case.

I just don't understand why all of the image f(L) can be a sublattice of L' when f is a homomorphism from L to L'. I learned that all subsets of a lattice don't have to be a sublattice at all. If I don't understand wrong, it's not about the elements of the lattices actually but about the operator differences between them.

So why there is not a possibility of a non-inherited operator of f(L), or a non-sublattice lattice of the L' as f(L)?

Comment: If $f:L\to L'$ is just a map, then $f(L)$ might not be a sublattice of $L'$. Homomorphisms are maps with something else...

Comment: Thank you, so can we say homomorphisms are possible just for groups, lattices (& categories) but not for sets?

Comment: Homomorphisms are possible for sets: it's just that set homomorphisms are just maps. For example, a semigroup is a set with a binary operation $(S,\cdot)$; then a semigroup homomorphism is a map $f:S\to W$, where $W$ is another semigroup, which additionally satisfies $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. Can you use that, applied to the lattice operations and the definition of lattice to show that $f(L)$ is a sublattice of $L'$, in your context?

Comment: I think I understand now, f(L) is always a sublattice of L' (except when f: L→L′ is just a map) just because of the homomorphism part. If that wasn't the case then the function can work with any operation which doesn't necessarily includes the operation of L' lattice & in that case f(L) doesn't have to be a sublattice of L' because of that different operation possibility. I hope I understand the subject somewhat, thank you for your answers.